# how properties are stored in /etc/designs for design dialog

Tags: aem

I'm new to CQ5 and working on a project that deals with refactoring code that uses design dialogs.

Currently, I have a property declared as part of design dialog of my component. It creates a folder in /etc/designs/ for each template my component is used on. Is there a way we can make sure that those property values are stored at one particular configuration in /etc/design(as opposed to multiple)? I need to make sure only one set of configurations is used for all pages that use my component.

Thanks in advance!

Pallavi

Answer (score 2):

The designs are linked to the template and not the whole site.

Hence whenever you configure the component in design mode, the values are stored within the corresponding template under the `jcr:content` of the configured design page or under `/etc/designs/default/jcr:content` in case no design is configured.

As far as I know, there is no way to tell AEM to store all the design configurations under one single path, unless you are using absolute paths in your dialog / page configurations.

Comment: Thanks Rakhi4110 for your timely response. Could you please shed some light on this part - "unless you are using absolute paths in your dialog / page configurations."?

Comment: Here is my code, and it is relative, how can i make it absolute?

Snippet from dialog.xml:

<columnOption
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            allowEmpty="false"
                            fieldLabel="Column Widths"
                            name="./shc:columnOption"
                            optionsProvider="CQ.utils.WCM.getStyleOptions"
                            stylePath="shc:layouts"
                            type="select"
                            xtype="selection"/>

Comment: Snippet from design_dialog.xml:

<layouts
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Allowed Formats"
            name="./shc:layouts"
            xtype="textarea"/>

where shc:layouts is my property. Can I just change my design dialog like below?

<layouts
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Allowed Formats"
            name="/etc/designs/default/shc:layouts"
            xtype="textarea"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple templates in your site, there must be one master template (which render global components eg. header/logo/navigation & footer), and all other templates should extend master template to get these global components and change pagelayout for content section.

Saying so, if templates are structured & inherited properly, you should be able to set design dialog property on home page (created using master template) and all internal pages will be able to access those design property OOB. Though child pages (created using other template) can override those design property (if needed for that template) to break inheritance.