# AEM 6.1 - restrict component to specific template

Tags: frontend, adobe, aem

I've built a component for a new template in AEM 6.1 and I need it to only appear when authoring on that specific template (adding new components to that page and such). Main reason is there's **a lot** components in the sidekick and we want to clean it up; plus this component will only ever be usable on this template (because of authentication reasons). I'm told I need to achieve this via the allowedParent jcr attribute in the components .content.xml files.

Unfortunately upgrading from 6.1 isn't a possibility due to business reasons. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to make this component available via your design which is usually located at /etc/designs/[yourdesign]. There you will find a jcr:content node and all page templates below it. Just find there the right parsys and add this component.

See also: [how properties are stored in /etc/designs for design dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215773/how-properties-are-stored-in-etc-designs-for-design-dialog)

Comment: I appreciate the response, although I don't think this is the solution I'm after. I'm not able to make any changes to the etc because of the way our code base is set up (my changes wouldn't get pushed up). Thank - you though for the help!

Comment: when you have a standard project setup you have a ui.apps or content package which actually contains the /etc/designs content. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to have any design settings for your custom templates.
What we sometimes do, do the changes in design view and export it via Package